# Binary Serialization uninitialized array of struct

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have provided a minimal code to mimic the scenario. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Serialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] annotates = { "1", "2"};
            Guides[] g1 = new Guides[2];
            g1[0].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();
            g1[1].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();

            Guides[] g2 = new Guides[2];
            g2[0].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();
            g2[1].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();//to be commented later

            arrayStruct arrStr1 = new arrayStruct();
            arrStr1.guides_array = g1;

            arrayStruct arrStr2 = new arrayStruct();
            arrStr2.guides_array = g2;

            using (MoveSaver objSaver = new MoveSaver(@"C:\1.bin"))
            {
                MoveAndTime mv1 = new MoveAndTime();
                MoveAndTime mv2 = new MoveAndTime();
                mv1.MoveStruc = "1";
                mv1.timeHLd = DateTime.Now;
                mv1.arr = arrStr1;
                objSaver.SaveToFile(mv1);
                mv2.MoveStruc = "2";
                mv2.timeHLd = DateTime.Now;
                mv2.arr = arrStr2;
                objSaver.SaveToFile(mv2);
            }

            using (MoveSaver svrObj = new MoveSaver())
            {
                List<MoveAndTime> MVTobjs = svrObj.DeSerializeObject(@"C:\1.bin");
                foreach (MoveAndTime item in MVTobjs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.arr.guides_array[0].comments[0]);
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public class MoveSaver : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        FileStream fs;
        StreamWriter sw;
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public MoveSaver(string FileName)
        {
            this.filename = FileName;
            fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        }

        public MoveSaver()
        {

        }

        ~MoveSaver()
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }

        }

        public List<MoveAndTime> DeSerializeObject(string filename)
        {
            List<MoveAndTime> retList = new List<MoveAndTime>();
            MoveAndTime objectToSerialize;
            Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            while (stream.Position != stream.Length)
            {
                objectToSerialize = (MoveAndTime)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
                retList.Add(objectToSerialize);
            }
            stream.Close();
            return retList;
        }


        public bool SaveToFile(MoveAndTime moveTime)
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                bformatter.Serialize(fs, moveTime);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct MoveAndTime
    {
        public string MoveStruc;
        public DateTime timeHLd;
        public arrayStruct arr;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct arrayStruct
    { 
        public Guides[] guides_array;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct Guides
    {
        public string[] comments;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

In this code an struct contains multiple structures, one of which contains an array. Try the code and it compiles fine, but in the real scenario the whole array is not filled, so there would be other array elements unspecified. To see this effect (in action!) comment the line `g2[1].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();` and try the code now. You will face an error while deserializing. How can I avoid it? Should I define the structure containing the array as a class and new them all (hopefully I am looking for a solution of structure-based kind)?

**Edit:** 
I Changed the structs to class and by newing every instance it works fine. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Serialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] annotates = { "1", "2"};
            GuidesClass[] g1 = new GuidesClass[2];
            g1[0] = new GuidesClass();
            g1[0].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();
            g1[1] = new GuidesClass();
            g1[1].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();

            GuidesClass[] g2 = new GuidesClass[2];
            g2[0] = new GuidesClass();
            g2[0].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();
            g2[1] = new GuidesClass();
            //g2[1].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();

            array_cls  arrStr1 = new array_cls();
            arrStr1.guides_array = g1;

            array_cls arrStr2 = new array_cls();
            arrStr2.guides_array = g2;

            using (MoveSaver objSaver = new MoveSaver(@"C:\1.bin"))
            {
                M_T mv1 = new M_T();
                M_T mv2 = new M_T();
                mv1.MoveStruc = "1";
                mv1.timeHLd = DateTime.Now;
                mv1.arr = arrStr1;
                objSaver.SaveToFile(mv1);
                mv2.MoveStruc = "2";
                mv2.timeHLd = DateTime.Now;
                mv2.arr = arrStr2;
                objSaver.SaveToFile(mv2);
            }

            using (MoveSaver svrObj = new MoveSaver())
            {
                List<M_T> MVTobjs = svrObj.DeSerializeObject(@"C:\1.bin");
                foreach (M_T item in MVTobjs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.arr.guides_array[0].comments[0]);
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public class MoveSaver : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        FileStream fs;
        StreamWriter sw;
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public MoveSaver(string FileName)
        {
            this.filename = FileName;
            fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        }

        public MoveSaver()
        {

        }

        ~MoveSaver()
        {
            if (fs != null)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }

        }

        public List<M_T> DeSerializeObject(string filename)
        {
            List<M_T> retList = new List<M_T>();
            M_T objectToSerialize;
            Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            while (stream.Position != stream.Length)
            {
                objectToSerialize = (M_T)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
                retList.Add(objectToSerialize);
            }
            stream.Close();
            return retList;
        }


        public bool SaveToFile(M_T moveTime)
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                bformatter.Serialize(fs, moveTime);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class M_T
    {
        public string MoveStruc;
        public DateTime timeHLd;
        public array_cls arr;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class array_cls
    {
        public GuidesClass[] guides_array = new GuidesClass[10];
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class GuidesClass
    {
        public string[] comments;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, **why** are they structs? They don't look like typical structs (especially since they are mutable), and without a good reason they should be classes by default.

Comment: @Oded: "The input stream is not a valid binary format", and in the actual code the error is relevant to binary header. Try compiling the code with the line commented and you will see the error.

Comment: @Marc: I need a place to hold some variables base on user interaction, and I am implementing no method for them. Non of my structs need initialization of their variables. I don't think it differ to me if it is class or struct but it seems to me that struct should suffice. If I have to, or I am going to face serious issues regarding such array initializations in runtime and having jagged array please let me know now :D

Comment: @Yasser - the choice of struct vs class has **nothing**, repeat: ***nothing*** to do with whether it wants initialization or methods. Those are not value-types; they should not be structs. I have yet to figure out where this bizarre (but oft-repeated) notion comes from...

Comment: But to clarify; the same error manifests with classes; the problem here, IMO, is that BinaryFormatter is not intended to be appendable.

Comment: @Marc: I myself don't know where does this idea come from :D, I will try my best to fix it in my mind. I suggested the classes because I can initialize the whole array and create an upper bound for it. As you can see, i have set the dimension of Guide struct as in my code. Does it help?

Comment: @Yasser - that is pretty much irrelevant; the error still happens, right? But to stress, the struct vs class thing is unrelated to the error, but is IMO only going to make things more confusing, unnecessarily.

Comment: @Marc: I have changed from any struct to class and it worked out. please check the edit section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a play with the code, and I can repro for both struct and class; ultimately I suspect the issue here is that `BinaryFormatter` isn't designed to be appendable quite like that, i.e. I suspect it is misinterpreting data from the *next* object as part of the current.

FWIW, those **really** shouldn't be structs, and you are (IMO) horribly over-engineering the save/load code. I changed it so that the save method took a `List<MoveAndTime>`, and the load code returned a *single* `List<MoveAndTime>` (i.e. so there is only one outermost object in the stream) and it worked fine, supporting my theory.

If you need to be able to gradually append individual objects, I would suggest protobuf-net; you can use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` to write an object in a way suitable for append, and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` to read a *single* object from the stream, or `DeserializeItems` to read (as a sequence) all the items in the stream.

---

For example, using protobuf-net v2 (only available as code at the moment):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using ProtoBuf;


namespace Serialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] annotates = { "1", "2" };
            Guides[] g1 = new Guides[2];
            g1[0].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();
            g1[1].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();

            Guides[] g2 = new Guides[2];
            g2[0].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();
            g2[1].comments = (string[])annotates.Clone();//to be commented later

            arrayStruct arrStr1 = new arrayStruct();
            arrStr1.guides_array = g1;

            arrayStruct arrStr2 = new arrayStruct();
            arrStr2.guides_array = g2;

            using (Stream file = File.Create(@"1.bin"))
            {
                MoveAndTime mv1 = new MoveAndTime();
                MoveAndTime mv2 = new MoveAndTime();
                mv1.MoveStruc = "1";
                mv1.timeHLd = DateTime.Now;
                mv1.arr = arrStr1;
                Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, mv1, PrefixStyle.Base128, Serializer.ListItemTag);
                mv2.MoveStruc = "2";
                mv2.timeHLd = DateTime.Now;
                mv2.arr = arrStr2;
                Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, mv2, PrefixStyle.Base128, Serializer.ListItemTag);
            }

            using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(@"1.bin"))
            {
                List<MoveAndTime> MVTobjs = Serializer.Deserialize<List<MoveAndTime>>(file);
                foreach (MoveAndTime item in MVTobjs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.arr.guides_array[0].comments[0]);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public struct MoveAndTime
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string MoveStruc;
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public DateTime timeHLd;
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public arrayStruct arr;
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public struct arrayStruct
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public Guides[] guides_array;
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public struct Guides
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string[] comments;
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string name;
    }
}
```

v1 (available as a dll; more stable) would work almost the same, but doesn't support structs - only classes.

But to emphasise:

- they should be classes
- public fields are a bad idea